# How to prove that the difference between two consecutive squares is odd?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

**Prove that the difference between the squares of two consecutive numbers is always an odd number**

For two consecutive numbers $p, q \in R$ where $q=p+1$, it follows that 
$p^2 - q^2 = (p-q)(p+q)$. Moreover, $$p^2 - q^2 = (p-(p+1))(p+(p+1))$$ which gives $$p^2 - q^2 = -1(2p+1)$$
Hence the number is in fact odd.

My question is whether I should consider the case where $q=p-1$ too and is there a way to generalize it.

Comment: There's a very simple proof. Consecutive numbers have different parities, and squaring preserves parity. The difference of numbers with different parities is odd.

Comment: "consider the case where q=p−1 too"  No. Just say: Let $p$ be the smaller of two consecutive numbers and $q = p+1$ be the larger of two consecutive numbers.

Comment: But don't overlook the obvious!  $(p+1)^2 - p^2 = (p^2 + 2p + 1)-p^2 = 2p + 1$.

Comment: You have already covered the case where $q = p- 1$ (because your proof works if you swap $p$ and $q$).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you probably meant $p,q \in \textbf{Z}$. Now, if the smallest of two numbers is $n$, then you are interested in $(n+1)^2-n^2=n^2+2n+1-n^2=2n+1$ - which is odd.

Note: to avoid considering all cases, as you asked you can say (without lost of generality) that $n$ is the smallest among two of them, which will give you the fact that $n+1$ is the seocnd number.